# Python-Mongo Connection string using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am connecting mongodb through terminal using the following command

```
mongo --host "rs0arbiter.data.com:27019" --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile
/data/mongodb/mongodb2.pem --sslCAFile
/data/mongodb/ca2.crt --authenticationDatabase admin -u Admin
-p 123456
```

How do i connect the same through pymongo , i have tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection=MongoClient(     'rs0arbiter.data.com',  27019,  ssl=True,
ssl_certificate='/data/mongodb/mongodb2.pem',
ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
ssl_ca_certs='/data/mongodb/ca.crt' )
```

Also the pem and crt file should be placed in local or it should be located in server.

Thanks in Advance